# TypeScript: Making a field optional in an interface with specific type restrictions

Tags: typescript

Problem:
I am working on a TypeScript project and trying to define an interface called ICampaign. Within this interface, I have a field called campaignTypeDetails, which should be optional and limited to two specific sub-interfaces.

Here are the relevant interfaces I have defined:

```
interface CampaignDetailType {
    datetimeStart: string,
    datetimeEnd: string,
    devices: {
        id: number,
    }[],
}

interface TargetBasedCampaignDetailType extends CampaignDetailType {
    ageIntervals: {
        min: number,
        max: number
    }[],
    gender: "male" | "female" | "both"
};

interface ViewBasedCampaignDetailType extends CampaignDetailType {

};

interface ICampaign {
    campaignType: "target-based" | "view-based";
    campaignTypeDetails: TargetBasedCampaignDetailType | ViewBasedCampaignDetailType;
    example: string;
}
```

I expected that when I define an object of type ICampaign and provide a value for the campaignTypeDetails field, TypeScript would enforce that the value matches one of the defined sub-interfaces (TargetBasedCampaignDetailType or ViewBasedCampaignDetailType). However, when I tried to assign a value that doesn't match either sub-interface, TypeScript does not throw an error.

Here is an example of the code that doesn't produce any TypeScript errors:

```
const hll: ICampaign = {
  campaignType: 'target-based',
  campaignTypeDetails: {
    datetimeStart: "new Date()",
    datetimeEnd: "new Date()",
    devices: [{id:1}],
    ageIntervals: []
  },
  example: ""
}
```

Question:
How can I modify my ICampaign interface to make the campaignTypeDetails field optional and ensure that when it is provided, it must match either TargetBasedCampaignDetailType or ViewBasedCampaignDetailType?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `campaignTypeDetails?: TargetBasedCampaignDetailType | ViewBasedCampaignDetailType;`?

Comment: The issue is that your `ViewBasedCampaignDetailType` is actually empty and I would also suggest moving the `campaignType` to the union with the relevant `campaignTypDetails` so that you have discriminative unions which will make your work with this type a lot easier. Like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8BXN). Does this approach work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. `campaignTypeDetails` must match any of these types. I don't expect it to be optional field. So `?` does not make any sense

Comment: This approach work for me but I couldn't get the term "`ViewBasedCampaignDetailType` is actually empty". I would appreciate if you could also explain this.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that it only inherits the same thing as the `ViewBasedCampaignDetailType` does. I will explain better in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned in the comments that you didn't actually want to make the field optional, but since you didn't reflect that in the question body I will still make it optional.

Optionality is achieved using the `?` modifier:

```
campaignTypeDetails?: SomeType
```

The reason why you don't get an error is because `ViewBasedCampaignDetailType` has nothing unique that `TargetBasedCampaignDetailType` doesn't. Since `TargetBasedCampaignDetailType` is a `subset` of `ViewBasedCampaignDetailType` compiler isn't firing any issue, which is the way it works with this kind of union.

For example, if we change `ViewBasedCampaignDetailType` to:

```
type ViewBasedCampaignDetailType = CampaignDetailType & { random: string };
```

The following code will raise an error because every member of a union has unique properties:

```
const hll: ICampaign = {
  campaignType: 'target-based',
  campaignTypeDetails: {
    datetimeStart: "new Date()",
    datetimeEnd: "new Date()",
    devices: [{id:1}],
    ageIntervals: []
  },
  example: ""
}
```

If you won't have such properties then I suggest moving to [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), where each union member has a property that exists in all of the members and it is unique, which let's the compiler identify types.

This would make working with `ICampaign` a lot easier since you could determine the type of `campaignTypeDetails` just by checking the value of `campaignType`.
Example:

```
if(campaign.campaignType === 'target-based') {
   campaign.campaignTypeDetails // TargetBasedCampaignDetailType
}
```

To achieve this we need to group `campaignTypeDetails` together with `campaignType`:

```
type ICampaign = {
  example: string;
} & (
  | {
      campaignType: 'target-based';
      campaignTypeDetails?: TargetBasedCampaignDetailType;
    }
  | {
      campaignType: 'view-based';
      campaignTypeDetails?: ViewBasedCampaignDetailType;
    }
);
```

Testing:

```
const hll: ICampaign = {
  campaignType: 'target-based',
  campaignTypeDetails: {
    datetimeStart: 'new Date()',
    datetimeEnd: 'new Date()',
    devices: [{ id: 1 }],
    // ageIntervals: [], // expected error
    gender: 'male',
  },
  example: '',
};
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)